# My employer miscalculated the 30% ruling and overpaid

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I worked for a company from 2018-2021 for 3 years with the 30% ruling. Recently, they have discovered that they have overplayed my salaires since the 30% ruling was miscalculated. Hence, they paid me more and less to the tax authority(belastingdienst). They have made new pay statements with lower net wage than before and now wants to claim back the overpaid amounts.

Questions

Are they legally entitled to ask money back from me? Note : All my expenses in the Netherlands was based from the previous net salaires. Also, the mistake is so complicated and a non legal person cannot spot it.

Can belastingdienst ask the excess money back from me since my previous salary slips are modified? Am I the person responsible to pay this loonheffing amount or is it the company?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which country are you a citizen of?  This would obviously make a difference in the answer.

Comment: Comment rather than an answer, because I don't know, but: *they paid me more and less to the tax authority* — that would be between you and belastingdienst to fix, wouldn't it?  The employer withholds part of your income, which is essentially a service to you so you're not faced with a large bill upon your tax declaration.  If you've underpaid, you'll owe more taxes.  Not sure why the employer would ask money back from you.